# Live search using Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, symfony, jquery-autocomplete

I am creating a symfony2 project where I have a User table. I have to create a search box which shows suggestions while the user types in the name. And the user should only be able to select from the suggestion...Is [Jquery Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) the best way to achieve this..Is there any other efficient way that i can do this? Im using a MySQL DB..

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of doing this is using the [GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle)
I recently used it for the same purposes and it works great and is easy to integrate.